# Adjusting script on existing Google Sheets timesheet template to show totals in decimal format

Tags: google-sheets, decimal, duration

I am using this existing Google Sheets weekly timesheet template: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qgfcWdcrxVSJu0HoyUZp7w4pGrtHoH7iu-nMe5Qb7To/edit#gid=874047713

I am looking to change the format of both the daily totals and the weekly total to decimals, rather than H:MM. I have tried adding a multiplication of 24 in the formula of the cells and selecting Format>Automatic, but rather than displayimg a decimal, the result then goes from H:MM to H:MM AM.

What is the best way to get the "Total Hours" cells to display in decimal format?

Answer (score 0):

Go to *Format* -> *Number* -> *More Formats* -> *Custom number format*.

[image]

There you will find a lot of options, between them, several for formatting the numbers as decimals.

[image]